# Adding image in Magento via update layout

Tags: image, layout, magento, sidebar

I'm trying to figure out how to add images, etc. to the left sidebar portion of a 2 column  with left sidebar page in Magento using the layout update in the cms ->page->design portion of the admin area.

Is it possible to do this from the update layout xml area?  If not, could you explain how to create a module (or whatever else would be required).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in `base/default/layout/catalog.xml`, you will see an example of using a template with an image placeholder that can be specified in your Update Layout XML area:

```
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="core/template" name="left.permanent.callout" template="callouts/left_col.phtml">
            <action method="setImgSrc"><src>images/media/col_left_callout.jpg</src></action>
            <action method="setImgAlt" translate="alt" module="catalog"><alt>Our customer service is available 24/7. Call us at (555) 555-0123.</alt></action>
            <action method="setLinkUrl"><url>checkout/cart</url></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
```

So, in your Update Layout XML, you would write something like:

```
    <reference name="left.permanent.callout">  <!-- match this to the block name from above -->
            <action method="setImgSrc"><src>images/media/my_file_name.jpg</src></action>
            <action method="setImgAlt" translate="alt" module="catalog"><alt>Some text here</alt></action>
            <action method="setLinkUrl"><url>your/path</url></action>
    </reference>
```

You can adapt that by taking a copy of the template file `left_col.phtml` and making changes as you wish.